# Jhipster jdl import not updating table

Tags: jhipster

When I make any changes in jdl file and run

```
jhipster import-jdl myjdl.jh
```

It doesn't update the existing table in on disk H2 db. What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: I assume you restarted the java app and that you did not get any Liquibase error due to changelog checksums having changed, right?

Comment: No I got liquibase error.. is there anyway that I can wipe clean the table and liquibase configurations?

Answer (score 4):

When using the H2 Disk database, all of your data is stored in the `target` (mvn) or `build` (gradle) folders.  You can remove all data and tables by running `./mvnw clean` or `./gradlew clean`.  The new database tables will be created the next time you start your app.

In production, you should use Liquibase migrations which are detailed in [JHipster's "Using a Database" docs](http://www.jhipster.tech/development/#using-a-database).  The docs mention that these Liquibase migrations may work with H2 Disk (dev profile only) if you need to keep your data, but it is not tested.